# w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user (ERROR 11759)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm using spring Boot MVC Security with JPA Hibernate with Thymeleaf template engine.
I'm trying to create a user login with some users already stored in the DB(MySQL).
Whenever I use correct credentials, its okay. Also when I use a correct username with the wrong password, it works as it should displaying an error message.
But when I give a non-existing username that's not on the table(users) or leave the field blank, I have an error:

> ERROR 11759 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : An internal error occurred
>   while trying to authenticate the user."

Below are my codes that could be useful:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailServiceConfig myAppUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/home/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")
                .and().formLogin()  //login configuration
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/app-login")
                .usernameParameter("app_username")
                .passwordParameter("app_password")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
                .and().logout()    //logout configuration
                .logoutUrl("/app-logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .and().exceptionHandling() //exception handling configuration
                .accessDeniedPage("/error");
    }
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        auth.userDetailsService(myAppUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {
    @Autowired
    private UserInfoService userInfoService;
    @GetMapping("login")
    public ModelAndView login() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("login");
        return mav;
    }
    @GetMapping("home")
    public ModelAndView getAllUserArticles() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.addObject("userArticles", userInfoService.getAllUserArticles());
        mav.setViewName("articles");
        return mav;
    }
    @GetMapping("error")
    public ModelAndView error() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("error");
        return mav;
    }
}
```

UserDetailsService

```
public class UserDetailServiceConfig implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserInfoDao userInfoDAO;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        UserInfo activeUserInfo = userInfoDAO.getActiveUser(userName);
        GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(activeUserInfo.getRole());
        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails)new User(activeUserInfo.getUserName(),
                activeUserInfo.getPassword(), Arrays.asList(authority));
        return userDetails;
    }
}
```

Error:

```
    ERROR 12337 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.

org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: A granted authority textual representation is required
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:126) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:144) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:199) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A granted authority textual representation is required
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:181) ~[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority.<init>(SimpleGrantedAuthority.java:38) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.example.sample.configuration.UserDetailServiceConfig.loadUserByUsername(UserDetailServiceConfig.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:114) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 45 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I think you should grant permission to access the `/login` URL to all users by using `.antMatchers("/login").permitAll()` which should be declared before the `.antMatchers("/home/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")`.

Comment: Can you post a fuller stacktrace ?

Comment: @VPK I tried that but I can see the same error.

Comment: @PaulNUK I have posted the full stack trace.

Comment: is `UserInfo activeUserInfo = userInfoDAO.getActiveUser(userName);` actually throwing `UsernameNotFoundException` ? The error you are getting is because Spring security can't find any roles for a user. so perhaps it's returning a stub user with no roles rather than throwing the exception ?

Comment: Stacktrace says problem is UserDetailServiceConfig line 25.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@PaulNUK Yes, I had to change my code for UserDetailsService to check for any non-existing users in the database and it worked. I have made the correction. Thank you all!

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    UserInfo activeUserInfo = userInfoDAO.getActiveUser(userName);
    String dBuserName = activeUserInfo.getUserName();
    if(dBuserName == null){
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not authorized.");
    }
    GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(activeUserInfo.getRole());
    UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails)new User(dBuserName,
            activeUserInfo.getPassword(), Arrays.asList(authority));
    return userDetails;
}
```